# Найти минимальное значение словарь словарей (JSON)

Tags: python, json, dict, словарь, min

есть вот такого вида словарь словарей

```
   {'telegram': {'afghanistan': {'virtual18': {'cost': 12.19, 'count': 1000}, 'virtual23': {'cost': 16.25, 'count': 1000}}
```

и мне нужно отсортировать значение price по минимальной цене

```
import json
import requests

product = 'telegram'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
params = (
    ('product', product),
)
response = requests.get('https://5sim.net/v1/guest/prices', headers=headers, params=params)
r = response.json()

for smth in r['telegram']:
    if smth['cost']:
        print(smth)
```

а дальше я не понимаю как перебрать словарь или может функцию min() использовать, помогите разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот так примерно:

```
for country,tariffs in r['telegram'].items():
      print(country)
      print(sorted(tariffs.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['cost']))
```

Вывод:

```
afghanistan
[('virtual18', {'cost': 12.19, 'count': 1000}), ('virtual23', {'cost': 16.25, 'count': 1000}), ('virtual4', {'cost': 17.13, 'count': 570})]
albania
[('virtual18', {'cost': 12.46, 'count': 1000}), ('virtual23', {'cost': 25, 'count': 1000}), ('virtual4', {'cost': 26.25, 'count': 592})]
...
```

Хотя они там вроде и так отсортированы. Но я вам просто показал, как это всё перебрать и как сортировать. Задача у вас не совсем чётко сформулирована.

Если нужно найти для каждой страны минимальный тариф и потом отсортировать ещё страны по минимальному тарифу, то можно сделать так:

```
country_minprice = []
for country,tariffs in r['telegram'].items():
      country_minprice.append((country, min(tariffs.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['cost'])[1]['cost']))

print(sorted(country_minprice, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Вывод:

```
[('kyrgyzstan', 2.6), ('kazakhstan', 3.5), ('cambodia', 3.64), ('mongolia', 3.64),
...
('montserrat', 26.25), ('norway', 26.25), ('saintlucia', 26.25), ('italy', 27.38)]
```

Comment: Конкретная задача была, что я хотел найти минимальную цену из всех стран

Comment: @Seavegen По каждой стране своё минимальное если, то достаточно в моём коде вместо `sorted` использовать `min`. Или нужно одно число найти - минимум сразу по всем странам? Я так и не понял до конца формулировку.

Comment: нужно из каждый страны узнать минимальную цену за тариф, а лучше как то пересортировать например, из всех стран оказалось всех дешевле франция.

Comment: @Seavegen Дополнил ответ. Но вообще там никаких чудес, просто нужно посмотреть, какой элемент и как брать из кортежа, из словаря - и всё.